# Global JS variables within a user control scope?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, user-controls, global-variables, multiple-instances

Say you have a user control that uses a 3rd party JS API (uses dojo). You have a JS function `loadMap` that initialize some global variables for your control and hook up some events (from the 3rd party API) to your JS event handlers. In your event handlers you need to use the global variables you defined in `loadMap`.

**Problem:**
If I have more than one instance of this control in the same page, the globals would overwrite each other and wouldnt work.

**Question:**
How can I write the JS to have **global** variables within the scope of a control instance, if that makes sense? or any suggestion that would solve my issue.

Here is my control JS code (I minimized it to just show the problem), my globals are defined in the first 3 lines

```
//create the global variables
var mapVar;
var geocoderVar;
var toolbarVar;

function loadMap(divMap, divSearch) {
    ...
    // create the map 
    mapVar = new esri.Map(divMap, {
        zoom: 0,
        minZoom: 0,
        maxZoom: 10,
        lods: lods
    });     

    // create the geocoder 
    if (geocoderVar === null) {
        geocoderVar = new esri.dijit.Geocoder({
            map: mapVar
        }, divSearch);
        geocoderVar.startup();
    }
     //Hook up event handlers
    dojo.connect(mapVar, "onExtentChange", checkScale);
    dojo.connect(mapVar, "onLoad", createToolbar);       
}

function createToolbar(themap) {
    dojo.connect(mapVar, "onClick", function (evt) {
        if (canDrop === true) {
                point = evt.mapPoint;
            mapVar.graphics.clear();
           ...
        }
        ...

    });
     //create the toolbar variable
    toolbarVar = new esri.toolbars.Draw(mapVar);
    ...
    dojo.connect(toolbarVar, "onDrawEnd", addToMap);
}

 function checkScale(extent, delta, outLevelChange, outLod) {

     if (outLod.level == 10) {
         canDrop = true;
         window[controlName + '_toolbarVar'].activate(esri.toolbars.Draw.POINT, { showTooltips: false });
     }
     else {
         window[controlName + '_toolbarVar'].deactivate();
         canDrop = false;
     }
 }
 ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your code an anonymous local scope instead of writing everything globally:

```
(function(any, globals, you, need, to, pass, in, as, an, instance){
  //All code local to your control goes here
  global = "etc..."

....
}(any, globals, you, need, to, pass, in, as, an, instance));
```

By passing globals in as themselves, their local version overrides the global and prevents interaction.

Edit: To do this from an external JS file, simply declare your code as a single function, and call it once for each time your control loads. You would then include the JS file only once on your template:

in the js file:

```
var myFuncLib = function(any, globals, you, need, to, pass, in, as, an, instance){
      //All code local to your control goes here
      global = "etc..."

    ....
    };
```

in your control:

```
<script>
myFuncLib(any, globals, you, need, to, pass, in, as, an, instance);
</script>
```

The globals passed in may be clsses/id's specific to the control, DOM elements, other library resources, etc.

This solution is also approaching a library pattern called the "module pattern" There are a number of good resources available on this topic, not the least of which is the CommonJS spec (http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Modules/1.1) for implementing it in libraries, and the many script loaders that use this pattern.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the passing part? also if I do this wouldnt that mean that I need to have the JS within the user control code (compared to a separate file)?

Comment: You only need to pass if your code pulls in external variables, say, from the page it is on or from another library. The classic example is passing in "JQuery" as "$" so that $ does not collide globally, but can be used inside of the function scope. I will edit answer to show how to use externally.

Comment: it took me a couple of hours to get it right (thanks :)) but it seems that not all events are hooked up correctly. Would doing this affect the behavior of the script?

Comment: @JafarKofahi No, though it will make it so that one instance of the script cannot interact with another. WRT events, I would check to make sure your repeated control is not selecting items by ID - these must be unique or they will not work at all if they are repeated.

Comment: My code does not select anything by id, the only element Ids I use are the ones I pass to the function, I didnt pass globals to `myFuncLib` I just declared them within its definition

Comment: But the problem is with one of these variables `toolbarVar` that I initialize within an event handler, then I connect its event handler as follows `dojo.connect(toolbarVar, "onDrawEnd", addToMap);` but this event is never triggered?

Comment: ok nvm..I got it to work..I had to change the order of how things were being executed. thanks for the help